# Rearrange multi Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array about:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => t-shirt
            [1] => earing
            [2] => clock
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100.00
            [1] => 32.00
            [2] => 898.00
        )

)
```

I want to do this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => t-shirt
            [2] => 100.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => earing
            [2] => 32.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => clock
            [2] => 898.00
        )

)
```

Comment: I'd personally use a foreach loop, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If I were you, I would actually map that into an array of objects or an array of associative arrays.  The way you propose would cause you to lose your keys!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your input array */ );
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $data) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if (!isset($output[$i])) {
      $output[$i] = array();
    }
    $output[$i][] = $data[$i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well or like this.

```
  $test = array(
          'id' => array(
              1,2,3
          ),
         'product' => array(
                'tshirt', 'ewew', 'shorts'
          ),
         'price' => array(
             '10.00', '20.00', '30.00'
         )

        );

        $newarray = array();
        foreach($test['id'] as $k => $v){
            $newarray[$k] = array(
                $v, $test['product'][$k], $test['price'][$k]
            );
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($newarray);
```

Example [live](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iM77ze)

Comment: Thanks for help, I try your exemple and working well, Now I'm studing the code to understand it step-by-step.